# Reading a string in C until a "," is encountered

Tags: c

I took an assigment today where i had to read some strings with "," between them for example :John , mike,Kate. I have tried to you `scanf("%s[^,]", string)` but it would not work and all I did was reading all text like a whole string . I want those words to be different strings not one.

Comment: This can be easily done with [`strtok()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm).

Example is included on the linked page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close. You have used the `%s` format specifier when what you wanted was the `%[^...]` [format specifier](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). See the "Negated scanset."

```
scanf("%[^,]", string);
```

You may also wish to use a width specifier to prevent overflows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char foo[100] = {0};

  scanf("%99[^,]", foo);

  printf("%s\n", foo);

  return 0;
}
```

Additionally, you should get in the habit of checking the return value of `scanf` to ensure it was successful. `scanf` will return the number of items scanned. In this case we can check that it is `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char foo[100] = {0};

  if (scanf("%*[^,]", 99, foo) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("%s\n", foo);

  return 0;
}
```

To read multiple names separated by commas, you'll need to do a little more work, reading an entire line, then tokenizing it. You may find `getline` and `strtok` useful for this work.

Comment: When you are content that this answers your question, you can accept the answer.

Comment: @RaduMagetz, the scanset (`[^,]` in this case) is not a *modifier* to `s` or anything else.  It is the field descriptor itself -- an *alternative* to `s`.  So `%[^,]` reads one or more characters other than `,` into a string, which is what you want.

Comment: However, this suggestion still has problems.  It will not break at end-of-line, for example, and because it has no width specified, it can overrun the bounds of the destination array.  Also, this shows how to read *one* element from a comma-delimited list, but you'll have to do more work to read multiple such strings.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I felt it best to address the specific issue demonstrated in the question, and not offer a complete solution to the issue when no attempt at that has been demonstrated. I have edited to make suggestions on tackling this next step.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You have a solution for this problem ? Suppose i have a enumeration of three strings . I tried to do this : ' scanf("%1[^,] %1[^,] [^\n] ",a,b,c); ' and the output was a initialized with *John* and b with* Mike,Kate* and c has no initialization.